# Find maximum of two variables in R

Tags: r

I have this R code, and i want to assign to the Max Variable the maximum value of A and B
, would be something like :

```
Max<-(A,B)
```

How can i do it in R?
I searched but i couldn't find a max function.
Thanks

Comment: `max(A,B)` finds maximum value across all values in `A` and `B`.

Comment: `pmax(A,B)` gets you a vector of max(A[1],B[1]),...,max(A[n],B[n])

Comment: The first strategy should always try to use the (very useful) R help. Type ?max

Comment: For finding basic stuff without being swamped by functions in every other installed package, `help.search("max",package="base")` cuts down the signal-noise ratio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is literally `max`:

`Max <- max(A, B)`

Comment: Thank you, will accept your question in a few minutes :)

Comment: Actually if you try two vectors max(rnorm(5,0,1),rep(0,5)) it will yield just one number instead of a vector.